# What is the best way to create globally accessible List from JSON in Flutter?

Tags: android, json, list, flutter, dart

In my Flutter app i need to:

1. Load and parse data from .json and create a List of Classes representing one unit of that data.
2. Make sure that it is accessible everywhere from the app; almost every widget will make use of the data.

What is the best way to approach this? The data from JSON won't be modified, I just want to make different Lists out of it to put into ListView.builder.

Answer (score 0):

Create AsyncStorage setter method and save your json data as string and then use getter method to get the same json anywhere in the program.

```
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';


    export async function setUserResponse(data) {
        try {
            await AsyncStorage.setItem("userResponse", JSON.stringify(data));
        } catch (error) {
            alert(error.message);
        }
        // return;
    }

    export async function getUserResponse() {
        try {
            const data = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userResponse');
            return JSON.parse(data);
        } catch (error) {
            alert(error.message);
        }
        // return;
    }
```

Comment: I need a solution that works for Flutter, not React Native.

Answer (score 0):

you can use shared preference to save your data, 
 1. save all your data one by one
 2. Or save just encoded version of your json (it works faster if you fetch data from shared pref than rest api)